# Error al coger una imagen desde la galería - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En mi aplicación, necesito guardar en un `ImageView` una imagen tomada bien desde la cámara del móvil, bien desde la galería de fotos.

Para ello, tengo el método `getPhotoDialog()` en mi `Activity` que devuelve un `AlertDialog` en el cual elegiremos el lugar del cual vamos a obtener los datos.

La variable `_photoDialog` es un atributo definido como: `private AlertDialog _photoDialog`.

```
private AlertDialog getPhotoDialog(){
    if (_photoDialog == null){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddNewPet.this);
        builder.setTitle("Eleccion del lugar de donde tomar la foto");
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.camera, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                File photo = null; //Archivo temporal en el que guardar la fotografía
                try{
                    //Lugar donde vamos a almacenar la foto tomada por la camara
                    photo = PhotoUtils.createTemporaryFile("picture",".jpg", AddNewPet.this);
                    photo.delete();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                            "No se puede crear el archivo para tomar la foto");
                }
                mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo); //Guardamos la ruta donde se encuentra la foto
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent,ACTIVITY_SELECT_FROM_CAMERA); //entero para poder controlarlo en onActivityResult()
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.gallery, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                /* Con galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                Android nos lanza un diálogo de selección de qué fuente queremos la foto (galería, otras apps con imágenes, etc.)
                 */
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                //El int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE nos va a ayudar a recoger el resultado usando el método onActivityResult()
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        _photoDialog = builder.create();
    }
    return  _photoDialog;
}
```

El método `setPhotoButton` se encarga de agregar el listener a un `FloatingActionButton` para que al hacer click en el button, nos muestre el método anterior.

```
private void setPhotoButton() {
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*
            Comprobamos que el dialogo de elección de donde escoger la foto (cámara o galería) no se esté
            mostrando ya, y que además no se muestre cuando la aplicación se esté cerrando (provocaría el crasheo de la app).
             */
            if(!getPhotoDialog().isShowing() && !isFinishing())
                getPhotoDialog().show(); //Mostramos el dialogo para elegir de donde escoger la foto
        }
    });
}
```

Yo he probado a coger una imagen de la galería (el emulador de Android Studio no me deja tomar fotos y no he probado en un teléfono físico) por lo que se ejecutaría el `builder.setNegativeButton`.

De aquí pasamos al método `onActivityResult`:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //Recogemos el Uri del intent que ha reabierto nuestra Activity (data) usando data.getData().
        mImageUri = data.getData();
        getImage(mImageUri);
    }else if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECT_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //Tenemos el Uri guardado anteriormente (en la camara)
        getImage (mImageUri);
    }
}
```

Se ejecuta el primer `if` y se ejecuta el método `getImage`:

```
public void getImage(Uri uri){
    Bitmap bounds = photoUtils.getImage(uri);
    if (bounds != null){
       setImage(bounds);
    }else{
       showErrorToast();
    }
}
```

Aquí, cabe destacar que el objeto `photoUtils` pertenece a una clase creada a parte llamada `PhotoUtils`, inicializado como un atributo así: `private PhotoUils photoUtils`. La clase en cuestión es la siguiente:

```
public class PhotoUtils {
private static Context mContext;
private BitmapFactory.Options generalOptions;

//-----------CONSTRUCTOR-----------
public PhotoUtils (Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

public static File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext, Context context) throws  Exception{
    String path = context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/temp/";
    File tempDir = new File(path);

    if(!tempDir.exists()){
        tempDir.mkdir();
    }
    return File.createTempFile(part,ext,tempDir);
}

public Bitmap getImage (Uri uri){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try{
        inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options);
        inputStream.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.generalOptions=options;
    return scaleImage(options,uri,300);
}

public static int nearest2pow (int value){
    return value == 0 ? 0 :(32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value - 1)) / 2;
}

private Bitmap scaleImage(BitmapFactory.Options options, Uri uri, int targetWidth) {
    if (options==null)
        options = generalOptions;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    double radioWidth  = ((float) targetWidth / (float) options.outWidth);
    double radioHeight = ((float) targetWidth / (float) options.outHeight);
    double radio = Math.min(radioWidth,radioHeight);
    int dstWidth  = (int) Math.round(radio*options.outWidth);
    int dstHeight = (int) Math.round(radio*options.outHeight);
    radio = Math.floor(1.0/radio);
    int sample = nearest2pow((int)radio);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    if (sample<=0){
        sample=1;
    }
    options.inSampleSize = sample;
    options.inPurgeable = true;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream;
        inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
        if (sample > 1) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,dstWidth,dstHeight,true);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    return bitmap;
    }
}
```

La excepción que me sale es:

```
09-10 16:28:55.791 2515-2515/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: es.uclm.mylittlepets, PID: 2515
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1020, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4 flg=0x1 }} to activity {es.uclm.mylittlepets/es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.AddNewPet}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap es.uclm.mylittlepets.PhotoUtils.getImage(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap es.uclm.mylittlepets.PhotoUtils.getImage(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.AddNewPet.getImage(AddNewPet.java:109)
                                                                    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.AddNewPet.onActivityResult(AddNewPet.java:100)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Las líneas exactas son: `Bitmap bounds = photoUtils.getImage(uri);` del método `getImage(Uri uri)`

`getImage(mImageUri);` en el método `onActivityResult`

Supongo que debe ser algún tipo de error de retorno en la variable `bounds` y que quizá se produce en la clase `PhotoUtils`(¿¿¿???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de este metodo, la instancia de `photoUtils` tiene un valor null :

```
public void getImage(Uri uri){
    Bitmap bounds = photoUtils.getImage(uri);
    if (bounds != null){
       setImage(bounds);
    }else{
       showErrorToast();
    }
}
```

comentas que la inicializas, pero esto en realidad es una declaracion de la variable photoUtils de tipo PhotoUtils:

```
private PhotoUils photoUtils;
```

la inicializacion deberia realizarse de esta forma:

```
photoUtils = new PhotoUtils(getApplicationContext());
```

de hecho tienes otro detalle cuando haces uso del metodo `createTemporaryFile()` :

```
//Lugar donde vamos a almacenar la foto tomada por la camara
photo = PhotoUtils.createTemporaryFile("picture",".jpg", AddNewPet.this);
```

debes llamar el metodo pero de la instancia, debiera ser (photoUtils.):

```
photo = photoUtils.createTemporaryFile("picture",".jpg", AddNewPet.this);
```